# Why does ksh fail to capture standard error during nested command substitutions?

Tags: linux, shell, posix, ksh, io-redirection

I have the following shell script.

```
$ cat foo.sh 
foo()
{
    A=$(uname)
    printf "hello "
    bogus
}

echo output: "$(foo 2>&1)"
```

It produces the following output in bash, zsh, dash and posh. It makes sense because there is no such command called `bogus` on the system.

```
$ bash foo.sh
output: hello foo.sh: line 5: bogus: command not found
$ zsh foo.sh
output: hello foo:4: command not found: bogus
$ dash foo.sh
output: hello foo.sh: 5: foo.sh: bogus: not found
$ posh foo.sh
output: hello foo.sh:8: bogus: not found
```

But in ksh on Debian, it does not print the error message due to invoking the `bogus` command.

```
$ ksh foo.sh
output: hello
```

What went wrong?

In case, you want to know about the system details and the version details of the shell, please see the following outputs.

```
$ uname -a
Linux debian1 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u2 (2016-01-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ cat /etc/debian_version 
8.3
$ ksh --version
  version         sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01
$ dpkg -l bash zsh dash posh ksh | tail -n 5
ii  bash           4.3-11+b1      amd64        GNU Bourne Again SHell
ii  dash           0.5.7-4+b1     amd64        POSIX-compliant shell
ii  ksh            93u+20120801-1 amd64        Real, AT&T version of the Korn shell
ii  posh           0.12.3         amd64        Policy-compliant Ordinary SHell
ii  zsh            5.0.7-5        amd64        shell with lots of features
```

On a CentOS system I see the expected output.

```
$ cat /etc/centos-release 
CentOS release 6.7 (Final)
$ ksh --version
  version         sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01
$ ksh foo.sh
output: hello foo.sh[5]: bogus: not found [No such file or directory]
```

If I remove the command substitution in the function `foo`, then all shells produce similar output on Debian.

```
$ cat bar.sh
foo()
{
    printf "hello "
    bogus
}

echo output: "$(foo 2>&1)"
$ bash bar.sh
output: hello bar.sh: line 4: bogus: command not found
$ zsh bar.sh
output: hello foo:3: command not found: bogus
$ dash bar.sh
output: hello bar.sh: 4: bar.sh: bogus: not found
$ posh bar.sh
output: hello bar.sh:7: bogus: not found
$ ksh bar.sh
output: hello bar.sh[4]: bogus: not found [No such file or directory]
```

Why doesn't `ksh` print the error due to the `bogus` command in the first example on Debian but produces it on CentOS?

I found the following text in the [POSIX.1-2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03) standard:

> With the $(command) form, all characters following the open
>   parenthesis to the matching closing parenthesis constitute the
>   command. Any valid shell script can be used for command, **except a
>   script consisting solely of redirections which produces unspecified
>   results**.

I suspect that the part of the text that I have highlighted in bold font is responsible for causing unspecified behaviour in the above examples. However, I am not entirely sure because I couldn't find a definition for "a script consisting solely of redirections" in the standard.

I have two questions.

1. Can we prove with sufficient references to the standard or man
   pages whether the output of `ksh` in the first example is a bug or
   not?
2. How else can I capture the standard error written by a shell
   function where the shell function is performing command
   substitution?

Comment: I don't see how the boldened part is relevant. That's talking about something like `$(<filename)`, which you don't have in your script.

Comment: My guess is this is a ksh bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I searched about this issue and found following:

According to standard, this is an error because whenever a command is not found a  "command not found" error is given.

This is a bug which has been resolved in beta branch of ksh. Use that branch. I tested it in ubuntu and it works for me.

Here's how I did that:

```
git clone https://github.com/att/ast.git
cd ast
git checkout beta
bin/package make
cp arch/linux.i386-64/bin/ksh /usr/local/bin/ksh
```

There are many bugs in master branch's ksh. Just check commit logs in https://github.com/att/ast/commits/beta .

Comment: Your command sequence isn't consistent - you clone `ast` and then cd into `ast-open`, and I think the last line is supposed to be an install or copy command?

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that. Earlier that repo used to be called ast-open. Last is copy so that you can use ksh from any path

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to compile the beta version of ksh and test this issue. I could follow your steps and verify it as well. With the beta version of ksh, `ast/arch/linux.i386-64/bin/ksh --version` outputs `version         sh (AT&T Research) 93v- 2014-12-24` and `ast/arch/linux.i386-64/bin/ksh foo.sh` outputs `output: hello foo.sh[5]: bogus: not found [No such file or directory]`.

Comment: Yes, version in centos remains same because they are applying their own patches, one of which resolves this. Check the changelog : https://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/centos/updates/6.7/x86_64/Packages/ksh-20120801-28.el6_7.3.x86_64.html